# How can I stop being blocked by debugger statements in Jest?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs, istanbul

I'm just beginning to use Jest in my nodejs project. I have several test and all pass, but the last test I just coded is passing but is blocked in two places by Jest with code like this:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
cov_19rdmie87d().s[43]++;
debugger;

/* istanbul ignore next */
cov_19rdmie87d().s[53]++;
this debugger;
```

I have to hit f5 to continue twice while running my tests. How can I remove these debugging statements?

Comment: Just remove the `debugger` lines, and any breakpoints in your inspect sources.

Comment: @Shujath Thanks for that, it worked. I was confused since the problem showed in a read-only page shown by Jest that had lots of Jest-generated code. But indeed I some debugger statements in a file imported in the file being tested, that were not being hit in the execution path, so I never thought about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:
Remove `debugger` statements from your code and any kind of breakpoints from your inspect sources.

**Some more Wiki on Debugging in JS**

- Debugger : If you place a debugger; line in your code, Chrome will automatically stop there when executing. You can even wrap it in conditionals, so it only runs when you need it.
- Type debug(item.myFunc) in the console and the script will stop in debug mode when it gets a function call to item.myFunc
- When you need to debug JavaScript, Chrome lets you pause when a DOM element changes. You can even monitor its attributes. In Chrome Inspector, right-click on the element and pick a break on setting to use.

For more information, check out this article by raygun on [debugging in javascript](https://raygun.com/learn/javascript-debugging-tips).